# package installation not considered in playbook

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-16.04

I got some trouble with automating an installation using ansible.

I use this role (https://github.com/elastic/ansible-elasticsearch) to install elasticsearch on my ubuntu 16.04 server.

The role depends on the package python-jmespath, as mentioned in the documentation.

The role DOES NOT install the package itsself, so i try to install it before role execution.

```
- hosts: elasticsearch_master_servers
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: preinstall jmespath
    command: "apt-get install python-jmespath"

  - name: Run the equivalent of "apt-get update" as a separate step
    apt:
      update_cache: yes

- hosts: elasticsearch_master_servers
  become: yes
  roles:
    - role: elastic.elasticsearch
  vars:
    ...
```

When running the playbook i expect the python-jmespath package to be installed before execuction of role takes place, but role execution fails with

```
You need to install \"jmespath\" prior to running json_query filter"
```

When i check if the package is installed manually using dpkg -s python-jmespath i can see the package is installed correctly.

A second run of the playbook (with the package already installed) doesnt fail.

Do I miss an ansible configuration, that updates the list of installed packages during the playbook run ?

Am I doing something wrong in general ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW. It's possible to tag installation tasks and install the packages in the first step. For example

```yaml
    - name: install packages
      package:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        state: "{{ item.state|default('present') }}"
        state: present
      loop: "{{ packages_needed_by_this_role }}"
      tags: manage_packages
```

Install packages first

```sh
shell> ansible_playbook my-playbook.yml -t manage_packages
```

and then run the playbook

```sh
shell> ansible_playbook my-playbook.yml
```

---

Notes

1. This approach makes checking of the playbooks with "--check" much easier.
2. Checking idempotency is also easier.
3. With *`tags: [manage_packages, never]`* the *`package`*  task will be skipped when not explicitly selected. This will speed up the playbook.